# desktop/systray both missing on (k)ubuntu 15.04-64bit

Tags: 15.04

I updated to 15.04 (with kernel ending in 15) from 14.10 during the last month, while it was still Beta.
With the latest update on apr 25th, the plasma 5 desktop has totally disappeared. No background, no systray, no K-startbutton. I can't right-click on the desktop, as I could before, to bring back the systray.
I have tried to change the Nvidia driver for my Gforce 9500, and renaming the .kde-folder.
I can start with the Gnome desktop, but would very much like to get the KDE-desktop back.
I'm running 64 bit, with 16 Gb RAM, on a asus m4a77td pro MB, with a AMD Phenom II X6 1090T CPU

Comment: seems to be this prob: Black desktop on login with plasmashell crash (https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=125034), but still no solution other than deleting the plasma-related files in .cache

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all elements in folder ".cache" in your home.

You may lose the taskbar, but catch your desk and you can add again.